# Optimization/Concurrency JAVA: reading CSV file, parsing data to double then doing calculations on the values

Tags: java, performance, csv, concurrency, arraylist

I'm working on a data analyzing program in Java. The data is from car sensors, and it's delivered in a CSV format. It needs to the read, parsed to double then "converted" (say from a 5/12 Volt value to G-forces/mph/% throttle opening/% braking force, etc.). The data files are going to be up to about 200MB in size.

What I'm currently doing is reading the data with a BufferedReader, splitting the tokenz with indexOf() and substring(), parsing them to double with parseDouble, adding them to an ArrayList of ArrayLists with doubles (one ArrayList for each token, there's maximum about 20 tokens). After the arraylists are made I have to convert the doubles, which means using polynomials on each value (this seems to be taking up most of the time, more than 2/3 of it).

The whole sequence is about 7 seconds for sample data of 240 000 lines with 20 tokens. I'm wondering how I can improve this. I've been thinking about using streams and concurrency for the file-reading and parsing, but it seems the biggest problem is the polynomial-math. The code I'm using to calculate the converted values is:

```
pol0 + pol1 * value + pol2 * Math.pow(value, 2) + pol3 * Math.pow(value, 3)
         + pol4 * Math.pow(value, 4);
```

where polX is the polynomials and value is the double-value I'm converting. This is of course different depending on how many polynomials I have available.

So, does any of this make any sense? And if so, any suggestions on how to improve the performance of this process?

Thanks for a great site with many helpful users. :-)

Comment: May be it is better to profile your application first? There are a lot of good Java profilers which can show you the real bottle-neck in your code.

Comment: Also, comparing to a lot of reads, value parsing, ArrayList creations (and expansion supposedly) polynomial-math seems to be not the slowest part of the code..

Comment: Well, right now it isn't the slowest part anymore after getting rid of Math.pow the execution time is halved. I'm pretty sure the slowest part now is the substring-ing and parsing. Performance is good now compared to the requirement specification, so I'm not too worried. I tried creating ArrayList with the max size right away, it didn't seem to increase performance much (down from about 3100ms total to 3000ms).

Answer (score 2):

The `Math.pow(value, 2)` is pretty expensive.  This uses log + exp.  In stead you can use plain multiplication which is much faster.

```
double value2 = value * value;
double value3 = value * value2;
double value4 = value2 * value2;
double p = pol0 + pol1 * value + pol2 * value2 + pol3 * value3
     + pol4 * value4;
```

Another approach is to multiply as you go

```
double p = (((pol4 * value + pol3) * value + pol2) * value + pol1) * value + pol0;
```

---

ArrayLists of double is an expensive structure (mostly overhead).  It is several times larger than a double[].

e.g.

```
double[] buffer = new double[1024];
List<double[]> list = new ArrayList<>():
while((line = ....) {
  int used = 0;
  // found a double
  buffer[used++] = Double.parseDouble();
  double[] doubles = new double[used];
  System.arraycopy(buffer,0,doubles,0,used);
  list.add(doubles);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I agree; and you can take the product of the preceding power too; ex. if you precalc pol2' = pol2/(pol1*pol1), then you can use pol0 + (pol1 * value) + (pol2' * (pol1 * value) * value) and avoid Math.pow

Comment: The reason for using this approach in the first case is, the CPU can calculate `value3` and `value4` in parallel.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will look into using arrays instead. Will this help with execution times or mostly with memory usage?

Comment: More memory usage (factor of 4) than performances (a few tens of percent)

Answer (score 0):

There is a more efficient method for polynomial calculation:

```
double r = pol4;
r = value*r + pol3;
r = value*r + pol2;
r = value*r + pol1;
r = value*r + pol0;
```

Comment: I used this method now, went from 7200ms to 3200ms. Thanks a bunch, gotta remember to look more into the API what the methods actually do (Math.pow is obviously not very fast).